# Calculating CRC Checksum for ALAsset

Tags: objective-c, crc, alassetslibrary, crc32, alasset

I'm trying to calculate the CRC checksum for an ALAsset. My goal is to save all the CRCs and compare them at a later time to see if the asset has been changed, but every time I generate a CRC for the same asset, I get a different result.

To generate CRC:

```
#import "CRC32.h"
#import <zlib.h>

@implementation CRC32

+ (uint32_t)CRC32Value:(NSData*)data
{
  uLong crc = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
  crc = crc32(crc, [data bytes], [data length]);
  return crc;
}

@end
```

How it is used:

```
void(^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) 
  {         
    if(result == nil) 
    {
      return;
    }

    CrawlAssetData *assetData = [[CrawlAssetData alloc] init];
    [assetData setCrc:[CRC32 CRC32Value:[NSData dataWithBytes:&(result) 
                                                       length:sizeof(result)]]];
```

Here are my results when generating the CRC on different occasions for the same asset:

id: 17575
url: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=BB282CBD-F5B1-4771-B48B-E021224C7384&ext=JPG
filesize: 1394332
**crc: 3605102491**
creationtime: 2456085.397025

id: 17826
url: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=BB282CBD-F5B1-4771-B48B-E021224C7384&ext=JPG
filesize: 1394332
**crc: 1383370697**
creationtime: 2456085.397025

As you can see, the filesize and url are the same but the CRC is different.

Am I calculating the CRC wrong? Or should I be using a different part of the ALAsset to generate the CRC? Perhaps some data is different every time an ALAsset is retrieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
[assetData setCrc:[CRC32 CRC32Value:[NSData dataWithBytes:&(result) 
                                                   length:sizeof(result)]]];
```

...is calculating the CRC of the *address* of your ALAsset instance, not its data.

You can verify this by splitting the line:

```
NSData *crcData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&(result) 
                                 length:sizeof(result)];
NSLog( @"crcData length: %d", [crcData length]);
[assetData setCrc:[CRC32 CRC32Value:crcData]];
```

My guess is that in the output you'll see `crcData length: 4`.

Based on a follow up comment by the question asker (with a correction) the code to do this is:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer
                         fromOffset:0
                             length:rep.size
                              error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer
                                    length:buffered
                              freeWhenDone:YES];   
uint32_t CRC32 = [CRC32 CRC32Value:data];
[assetData setCrc:CRC32];
```

In particular, note that `sizeof(NSData*)` (or `NSData *a; sizeof(A)`) is always going to be the size of a *pointer* (4 on 32 bit systems like the iPhone, 8 for 64 bit Mac OS X), not the length of the byte data stored in the `NSData`. There's no normal reason to get the `sizeof()` a NSObject *pointer*.

Comment: Thank you very much! What a simple mistake. I reused some other code that was using the address and forgot to take it out.

Here was the fix:

`[assetData setCrc:[CRC32 CRC32Value:[NSData dataWithBytes:([data bytes]) 
                                         length:sizeof(data)]]];`

Comment: Final fix:

`ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];
    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
    NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
    [assetData setCrc:[CRC32 CRC32Value:[NSData dataWithBytes:([data bytes]) 
                                                       length:sizeof(data)]]];`

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I'm not familiar with the Assets Library, and it seems odd that this is the best way to get raw data out, but it looks like you're right. I'm going to edit that into my answer for anyone looking at this question in the future.

Comment: Oh, I looked deeper. Your code won't do it. You're using sizeof on a class instance, which will always be 4. I'll post corrected code.